# HDFS blocks issue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

when I run fsck command it shows total blocks to be 68 (avg. block size 286572 B). How can I have only 68 blocks?

I recently installed CDH5 with version: Hadoop 2.6.0

-

[hdfs@cluster1 ~]$ hdfs fsck /

```
Connecting to namenode via http://cluster1.abc:50070
FSCK started by hdfs (auth:SIMPLE) from /192.168.101.241 for path / at Fri Sep 25 09:51:56 EDT 2015
....................................................................Status:     HEALTHY
 Total size: 19486905 B
 Total dirs: 569
 Total files: 68
 Total symlinks: 0
 Total blocks (validated): 68 (avg. block size 286572 B)
 Minimally replicated blocks: 68 (100.0 %)
 Over-replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)
 Under-replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)
 Mis-replicated blocks: 0 (0.0 %)
 Default replication factor: 3
 Average block replication: 1.9411764
 Corrupt blocks: 0
 Missing replicas: 0 (0.0 %)
 Number of data-nodes: 3
 Number of racks: 1
 FSCK ended at Fri Sep 25 09:51:56 EDT 2015 in 41 milliseconds


The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY
```

-

This is what I get when I run hdfsadmin -repot command:

[hdfs@cluster1 ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -report

```
Configured Capacity: 5715220577895 (5.20 TB)
Present Capacity: 5439327449088 (4.95 TB)
DFS Remaining: 5439303270400 (4.95 TB)
DFS Used: 24178688 (23.06 MB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 504
```

-

Also, my hive query does not start MapReduce job, could it be above issue?

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are chunks of data that is distributed in the nodes in the File System. So for example if you are having a file of 200MB, there would infact be 2 blocks of 128 and 72 mbs each.

So do not be worried about the blocks as that is taken care of by the Framework. As the fsck report shows, you have 68 files in HDFS and hence 68 blocks.